# Oracle DB user can only log in on localhost

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Trying to create user (`abc`) to connect to database from my workstation. 
 VM with Oracle DB on Virtual Box (from their [Database App Development VM)](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html));

- `abc` can connect using SQL developer work on localhost inside the VM.
- Listener is as configured by default.
- I can connect to DB from my workstation as sys(SYSDBA), HR, or system(default) using SID orclcdb.

When I try to connect with abc I get

> ORA-01017 (invalid username/password; logon denied.)

I have granted all privileges to `abc`; not sure if I need to grant specific roles as well?

Comment: Could this be your problem? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143286/why-cant-i-establish-a-connection-to-the-local-oracle-database-from-within-the